# convert matlab to python with index

Tags: python, matlab

I'm converting matlab code to python

```
  A = np.eye(HP)
    for i in range(0,HP-2):
        for j in range(0,HP-i-1):
            if j > col:
             A[j + i, i] = 0
            else:
                A[j + i, i] = B[j+1]
```

i have this msg when i run it

```
 Ainf[j + i, i] = alpha[j+1]
```

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm: IndexError: list index out of range (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994351/algorithm-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab indexing is [1, n]. Python indexing is [0, n). you'll have to update the indexing to account for this.